# Analyzing Independently Pooled Cross Sectional data (TIme series)

Tags: time-series, stata, panel-data, cross-section

I am new with time-series data analysis.  It seems that there is some confusion in terminology (Panel, and time-series cross-sectional).  But my question is general in nature.
How do I analyze a dataset of independently pooled cross-sectional data (ie: 5 years of country level data, each year contains a random sample of countries.) This is not a strict Panel analysis.

Should this be done using the stata "regress" or "xtreg" command?  I know I can do it with strict panel data (also using year dummies, and cluster-robust standard errors).  But I'm not certain about using time-series data that is not a strict panel.